# Count records which occurs more than once in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

very probably easy, but not for me;-)
I found nothing similar in already answered questions.

There is column 'Values' with following records:

A,A,B,C,D,D,D,E,E,F,G,H

What I want to get is the count of records which occurs more than once, in this example 3 (2xA, 3xD, 2xE = 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you required 3:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT values 
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY values 
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t
```